# nifi extracttext from a JSON attribute that is commar delimited

Tags: apache-nifi

Hi I am fairly new to apache nifi and I need to extract a suburb from a json string

flowfile looks like this

```
                                                    \/
{"UserName:"John Doe", "Address":"22 smith st, Smithville, NSW","IP":"10.10.10.1}
```

The suburb is always the 2nd last value in the commar delimited list of the "address" attribute. Sometime it wont be in the 2nd position from left as there might be something like

```
{"UserName:"John Doe", "Address":"Level 10, 22 smith st, Smithville, NSW","IP":"10.10.10.1}
```

I have tried to use extract text with regex `[^,]+(?=,[^,]*$)`
but was not able to make it extract the attribute correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't use extractText for extract the Json values and it is not proper way to do it.

You can EvaluateJsonPath processor for extract "Address" of the Json attribute with help of following configurations.

Just configure those attributes for destination to be **"flowfile-content"** and Return Type to be **"Json"**.

Now you have to add new property named `"Address":$.Address`.

Here you can receive address of json will be stored in attribute named "Address" then you can extract 2nd column of the suburb present in Address like `${Address:substringBeforeLast(','):substringAfterLast(',')}.`

Look at this expression guide which may useful for you.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#substringafterlast
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#substringbeforelast